# 'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, wmic

I need to run this script I made. This batch should copy compiled program on STM32 Nucleo. It uses `wmic` to find Nucleo's virtual drive's letter by it's label:

```
@echo off
for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "NODE_F446RE"') do set nucleo_drive=%%D
IF EXIST %D%\DETAILS.TXT (
  IF EXIST main.bin (
    @echo on
    xcopy main.bin %D%
    @echo off
    echo Copied main.bin on nucleo
  ) ELSE (
    echo Binary not found. Run `mingw32-make` in this directory to compile the project.
  )
) ELSE (
  echo Nucleo drive not found. If needed, edit the `find "NODE_F446RE"` part of this script to refference your nucleo volume name.
)
```

But I get this error:

```
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I ensured that Windows Management Instrumenation service is running. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Try absolute path to `wmic`, it should live in `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This indicates that the `wmic` utility's directory is not found on your `PATH`. Open the advanced System Properties window (you can open the System page with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>) and on the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables. In the section for system variables, find `PATH` (or any capitalization thereof). Add this entry to it:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

Note that entries are delimited by semicolons.

Comment: +1 for a shortcut I didn't know about :)

Comment: Before going through these steps, it's probably worth navigating to this folder in an elevated (run as admin) command-line window to ensure the command is really there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem` on the path already, but a recent USB device driver I installed additionally added `C:\Windows\System32` to the *end* of my path, and this stopped Windows from finding the wmic command. When I removed the trailing `C:\Windows\System32` from the path, wmic was found again.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using `C:\Windows\System32` in the path, I was getting the same warning while installing Tails operating system on an USB stick.

When I change this to: `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem`, everything gets sorted and the warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 11, Microsoft has [removed WMIC from the latest Insider builds](https://winaero.com/microsoft-removed-the-wmic-tool-from-windows-11-dev-builds/).

Instead, you should now use Powershell commands.

To list all WMI Powershell commands, you can run `Get-Command -Noun WMI*`.

Comment: Well what commands specifically?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica Run `Get-Command -Noun WMI*` to list all WMI-related Powershell commands.